# Back key react native android

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to go back to previous view in my react native app using this code

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  BackAndroid, 
  Navigator
} = React;

var HomePage          = require('./HomePage');

class DetailsPage extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>
            {this.props.description}
        </Text>
      </View>
  )
  }
}
BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
     this.props.navigator.pop(); // line 32
    return true;
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  text:{
    color:'#000',
    textAlign:'center',
    fontWeight:'bold',
    flex:1,
    fontSize:20
  },
});
module.exports = DetailsPage;
```

While debugging I see that the back event is detected successfully but it crashes at this line `this.props.navigator.pop()` giving me this error.

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefinedhandleException @
>   D:\React\Kora\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\JavaScriptAppEngine\Initialization\ExceptionsMana…:61handleError
>   @
>   D:\React\Kora\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\JavaScriptAppEngine\Initialization\InitializeJava…:80ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
>   @
>   D:\React\Kora\node_modules\react-native\packager\react-packager\src\Resolver\polyfills\error-guard.…:28guard
>   @
>   D:\React\Kora\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\MessageQueue.js:43callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>   @
>   D:\React\Kora\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\MessageQueue.js:86onmessage
>   @ debuggerWorker.js:39

[image]

my guess it that `this.props` can not be accessed out side the class braces but I don't know how to overcome this problem. if I put the `BackAndroid.addEventListener` inside the class it gives me error

> UnExpectedToken

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**edit: BackAndroid is now deprecated. You should probably be using [BackHandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler.html) instead.**

In your event, `this` does not refer to what you think it refers to.
In this case, it refers to the object on which the event is called.

The way I did it in my react-native app, was by adding the event in the `componentDidMount()`-function of my main component (the component in which the `Navigator` is rendered).

I added it there the (sort of) following way:

```
class ViewComponent extends Component {

    ...

    componentDidMount() {
        //the '.bind(this)' makes sure 'this' refers to 'ViewComponent'
        BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function() {
            this.props.navigator.pop();
            return true;
        }.bind(this));
    }

    ...
}
```

**It should work like this in your project.**

The `componentDidMount()` is fired right after the initial render. You could probably also use `componentWillMount()`. So it adds the event right after the first time it renders. It only gets fired off once, so there are no overlapping events and stuff like that.

I wouldn't, however, add the event listener on scenes. It brings the risk of perhaps adding the event twice. Although I'm not sure if adding that event twice would actually change anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked but with `this.props.navigator.pop();` instead of `this.navigator.pop();` .. please Edit the answer to accept it

Comment: oh, looked over that one. glad it could help though

Comment: @Stinodes This doesn't work for me :/ it gives me this error `undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.props.navigator.pop()')`. I have the exact same code you posted in the component where I have my `Navigator`

Comment: @corasan Are you sure you passed your navigator as a prop to your component?